# I need helping sorting cards for poker

Tags: java

c1 and c2 are from my card object, and p. stuff is from my player class. I am trying to swap the hand so that the cards are in order from least to greatest. Cards are dealt, they are just not in order. If you need me to put up my player class and card class I'll be more than happy to. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void SortCards(Player p)
{
    Card c1 = null;
    Card c2 = null;

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    int card1 = 0;
    int card2 = 0;

    String p1;
    // pull out player
    // get card
    // set at positions

    // loop goes to the size of the hand
    for ( a = 0; a < p.handSize(); a++)
    {
        c = a;
        b = a + 1;

        for (b = 0; b < p.handSize(); b++)
        {
            c1 = p.Hand.get(b); 
            c2 = p.Hand.get(c); 

            card1 = c1.getValue(); 
            card2 = c2.getValue(); 


                if (card1 < card2)
                {
                    c = b;
                }
            b = b + 1;  
        }
        p.Hand.setElementAt(c2, card1);
        p.Hand.setElementAt(c1, card2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider implementing Comparable (or write a Comparator) and just using sort.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Comparable in your Card class and use a List and Collections.sort().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that you shouldn't be re-implementing your own sort function. Maybe you want to anyway. (Maybe this is for school, and your teacher wants you to.) In that case, the code you've written here has a lot of issues so it isn't easy to point out one quick correction that's going to get you from here to a working solution, but here's somewhere to start: look for a moment at all the places "b" is modified. In the outer loop, you set it to c+1, but then immediately reset it in the inner loop to 0. The inner loop increments it every iteration, but you also have a separate "b = b + 1" statement so it's getting double-incremented each time.

You should have a very good idea of the purpose of each of your variables. If possible, you should name your variables according to that purpose so that your code is intelligible to you and others. It's easy to get confused when your variable names are all single letters.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also agree that you shouldn't re-implement your own sort function. If still want to do so take a look at the "bubble sort" algorithm. It is an easy sort algorithm. I modified your code so that it use the bubble-sort algorithm. But i didnt test it and also dont be a java-programmer so may it dont work but i guess it do :)

```
public static void SortCards(Player p) { 
  Card c1 = null;
  Card c2 = null; 
  boolean unsorted=true;

  while (unsorted){
     unsorted = false;
     for (int i=0; i < p.handSize() - 1; i++) 
        c1 = p.Hand.get(i); 
        c2 = p.Hand.get(i+1); 

        if (c1.getValue() < c2.getValue()) {                      
           p.Hand.setElementAt(c2, i);
           p.Hand.setElementAt(c1, i+1);
           unsorted = true;
        }          
  } 
}
```